# Unable to auto trigger pipeline from one repo to another azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to trigger a pipeline in another repo. My pipeline in repo2 and the code in repo1. whenever I commit any changes in repo1 or repo2 it should trigger the pipeline. I have created new project in Azure Devops Just to test this, since I see in someplaces it should work when the pipeline is in the main branch.

I have created Project called DevTest. bydefault, Its having a repo called Devtest. I have created another repo devopstriggertest, I have added the pipeline in there. Here is the content of the pipeline in devopstriggertest repo. Its triggering for all the changes in devopstriggertest repo where the pipeline is there but not for the repo devtest. Both changes are happening in main. my pipeline is already in main.

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: self
      name: DevTest/DevopsTriggertest
      type: git
      ref: main
      trigger: 
        branches:
          include:
            - main
            - releases/*
            - features/*
    - repository: repo
      name: DevTest/DevTest
      type: git
      ref: main
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - main
        batch: true

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

I can see both the repo are listed in resources.

Comment: In the name you should use this syntax `name: OtherProject/MyAzureReposGitRepo` so it should be in your case `name: DevTest/DevTest`

Comment: I have tried it. Its not triggering it. Updating the Original question with the same. Thanks